# Visio 2016- shape lines automatically get thicker when shape size is increased - how do I disable this?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

I would like to resize shapes in Visio 2016 without changing the line thickness of the shape.

For example, in a circuit diagram, I would like to change the length of a Ground Shape or Transmission Line Shape while maintaining the current line thickness. If the Ground and Transmission Paths all have different line widths, the diagram cannot be used.

I have tried un-protecting the shapes on the Developer Tab, but this does not work.

I also need to be able to change a shape length without automatically changing the shape height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some of these shapes there is now a formula that sets the line width from the shape's size. You need to edit this formula from something like:

**=GUARD(Width*0.04)**

to

**=4pt**

or whatever size you want.

You will need to do this in the shapesheet editor.