# Editing ShapeSheet in Visio makes no difference

Tags: microsoft-visio

I'm making electric diagrams in Visio 2019. My problem is that when I try to resize a stencil, as the Inductor shape, the line width of the shape is resized proportionally to the shape width, but I don't want it.

Reading the link below I learned that by default the LineWeight is set in the ShapeSheet as
**=GUARD(Width*0.04)**, and replacing it by **=4pt** I could resize the shape keeping the line width constant, but it is not happening. Anything I type in the LineWeight field in the ShapeSheet makes no difference: the line width keeps linked to the shape width.

[Visio 2016- shape lines automatically get thicker when shape size is increased - how do I disable this?](https://superuser.com/questions/1370053/visio-2016-shape-lines-automatically-get-thicker-when-shape-size-is-increased)

How can I resize the Inductor shape without changing the line width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a grouped shape and the part of the shape to create the coils is deeper down within the group. Open the group shape (don't ungroup it) and open the 2nd shape within the group. That's the one that you want.